# Is it possible to edit the page_obj before passing template?

Tags: python, django

I can catch `<class 'django.core.paginator.Page'>` in get_context_data function of django view class.

What I want to do is alter the showing item and get it back to `<class 'django.core.paginator.Page'>` again.

`django.core.paginator.Page` source code is here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/core/paginator/

I found it has `object_list`,so I try to change

```
def get_context_data(self):
    temp = super().get_context_data() 
    print(type(temp['page_obj'])) #<class 'django.core.paginator.Page'>
    new_object_list = []
    for t in temp['page_obj'].object_list:## I can iterate the item here.
        # make new_object_list here

    temp['page_obj'].object_list = new_object_list 
    print(temp) # nothing changes
    return temp
```

However `object_list` doesn't change.

Comment: I think you are mixing up two different variables - `temp['object_list']` and `temp['page_obj'].object_list` (both of which store the same list initially). With the code you have provided, ``temp['page_obj'].object_list`` is in fact modified. But if you just inspect the `temp` dict you will only see the value for `temp['object_list']` .

Comment: Also you're most likely accessing `{{ object_list }}` in the template, rather than `{{ page_obj.object_list }}`, which is what you have modified.

Comment: Thank you it solves. As you said I am confused by these two.  Now, I can edit the pagenated object as a I  want.